# How do I set Path Variables in Linux just like in windows?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, java-8

I downloaded JDK and have many softwares which use requires it. For eg: for eclipse I'll copy the jdk in java folder in eclipse root directory. As a result I have many copies of JDK all over my system. Also dont know how to configure it for Sublime Text. Is is possible to install java just like in windows. I mean that I just open terminal and type java and it executes instead of changing directory everytime.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your path variable but you really shouldn't be doing it like that.

Since you don't specify which version of Linux I'll be explaining it for Ubuntu and Arch Linux.

You should install openjdk packages with your package manager like so:

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

**Arch linux:**

```
sudo pacman -S jdk8-openjdk
```

You can then use the following commands to change between those versions:

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

**Arch Linux**

```
archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk
```

You can even launch specific apps in specific versions but this would be too much to cover for now.

---

## Setting the path variable regardless

To change your $PATH you have to either edit `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) for each user or global $PATH setting in `/etc/profile`.

Simply append another path to it like so:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/custom/path
```

You can also do:

```
PATH = $PATH:/custom/path
```

Comment: is OpenJDK same as the one provided by Oracle, because I knew about OpenJDK but thought it's different.

Comment: They are different but 99.99% of developers won't notice any differences. openjdk is pretty much standard in any linux environment though so it's a good practice to run your code against that :)

Comment: if you DO want to use the oracle one you can simply change the path as I have specified :)

Answer (score 0):

### Manual setup

Yes, just set `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` suitably. For example, see [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/). This should give something like the following:

#### ~/.bash_profile (or /etc/profile)

```
...
export JAVA_HOME=PATH_TO_JDK_ROOT/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:PATH_TO_JDK_ROOT/bin
```

### Linux distribution setup

Depending on your needs, you may otherwise opt to install your linux distribution JDK (using `apt-get`, `yum`, ...), thus avoiding manual steps to set the env vars.

#### Example: Ubuntu 16.04

To install the default JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

To install the Oracle JDK:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To select the active Java version when there is more than one installed:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: the guide was helpful

Comment: glad to hear that. Do you feel something is missing from this answer, for future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple installation is never a good idea. You can have windows like setup but in *nix OS you have to follow different steps.

The preferred location for JAVA_HOME or /etc/environment. So Open `/etc/environment` in any text editor and add the following line:

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/your jdk path"`   (Use your java path)

If needed run else skip to next step `source /etc/environment`

See if done right?

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: when I type echo $JAVA_HOME it displays the path but nothing happens when I type java

Answer (score 0):

If you want the appended value to be local to the script, do not prepend the export. Otherwise follow the example below which uses a search ability. I have appended to the PATH statement and want to export it so the PATH is known globally.  If I invoke a second terminal, the if statement prevent the PATH environment variable from being double appended.

if [ ! "/home/mylogon/bin" == *$PATH* ];
then
    export PATH=$PATH:/home/mylogon/bin:/home/mylogon/.local/bin"
fi